Java String split by empty lines including empty lines at the end
I have seen many questions and answers online, but it seems that I cannot find the case that I have.
String s = "a\nb\n\nc\n\n\n\n";
String[] split = s.split("\\R");
//is the same as this
String[] splitResult = {"a", "b", "", "c"};

But I would like the result to include array items that are at the end, where only new lines are. Something like this:
String[] s = {"a", "b", "", "c", "", "", "", ""};

Is this possible with any built in method or with the regex? Thanks!

I'm not sure that limit (second argument in the split method) helps with that. It just limits the number of items in the result. This is very simple case because I am working with much larger strings that has new lines at the end sometimes and I have to handle them correctly.

s.split("\R", -1);

look at this question: Java String split removed empty values

@Matjaz check the javadoc: "If the limit is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded."

Your desired outcome is incorrect btw: You have defined four empty strings whereas it should be three. Thus the answer of @BIBOO unit should suffice.

@maio290 I went to double check again. The documentation says "The array returned by this method contains each substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression or is terminated by the end of the string" I think returning 4 empty strings could be correct because after the last newline character is empty string then the end of string

String[] s = {"a", "b", "", "c", "", "", "", ""}; No, it would be String[] s = {"a", "b", "", "c", "", "", ""}; Look what happens, e.g. to the first a. The simplest way to get that would be s.lines().toArray(); The result: Object[7] { "a", "b", "", "c", "", "", "" } (JShell)

That API has a side note: This definition of line implies that an empty string has zero lines and that there is no empty line following a line terminator at the end of a string. So at the end of the day, wouldnt the correctness depend on what OP wants instead of what we think is correct?

That API has a side note: That's worth noting, but it doesn't seem to be relevant here.

You will have to use the two argument split() method of the String class. While you did mention that it limits the number of results, you overlooked the following:

limit > 0 – If this is the case, then the pattern will be applied at
most limit-1 times, the resulting array’s length will not be more than
n, and the resulting array’s last entry will contain all input beyond
the last matched pattern.
limit < 0 – In this case, the pattern will be applied as many times as
possible, and the resulting array can be of any size.
limit = 0 – In this case, the pattern will be applied as many times as
possible, the resulting array can be of any size, and trailing empty
strings will be discarded.

I tested the following:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "a\nb\n\nc\n\n\n\n";
    String[] split = s.split("\\R", -1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
}

Giving me the output:

[a, b, , c, , , , ]


I skimmed through the implementation but I missed that -1 somehow. Thank you very much for that! It turned out that it was 4 empty strings at the end afterall, just like I expected it to be.
